# Camera Synchronization OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera, timestamp, synchronization

I have stereo cameras systems.
In my program I catch the images from each camera in two threads. (one thread per camera).
After I receive the images from each camera, I want to process them with OpenCV. How I can say to my program, that the both camera threads got images and I can go to process them?

I have another question. Every received frame from the camera has a timestamp, which is specified by camera. How I can match the timestamp, so that I get images from two cameras, which were caught at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever wrote an application using OpenCV to display the frames captured by the camera? Start from there. The application below does that and convert each frame to it's grayscale version:

```
CvCapture *capture = NULL;
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1); //-1 or 0 depending on your platform
if (!capture)
{
    printf("!!! ERROR: cvCaptureFromCAM\n");
    return -1;
}

cvNamedWindow("video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while (exit_key_press != 'q')
{
    /* Capture a frame */
    color_frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if (color_frame == NULL)
    {
        printf("!!! ERROR: cvQueryFrame\n");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        // WOW! We got a frame! 
        // This is the time to process it since we are not buffering 
        // the frames to use them later. It's now or never.

        IplImage* gray_frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(color_frame->width, color_frame->height), color_frame->depth, 1);  
        if (gray_frame == NULL)
        {
            printf("!!! ERROR: cvCreateImage\n");
            continue;
        }

        cvCvtColor(color_frame, gray_frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvShowImage("Grayscale video", gray_frame);
        cvReleaseImage(&gray_frame);
    }
        exit_key_press = cvWaitKey(1);
}
```

Keep in mind that the frames are being retrieved inside a loop, and if you quit the loop you'll stop receiving data from the camera. It makes sense, right? This leaves you with 2 options:

- Process the frame right way. But if this processing is slow, you'll probably miss a few frames from the camera until the next cvQueryFrame() operation.
- Store the frame using some buffer mechanism so you can do the processing on another thread. This is a good approach if your processing technique is demanding on the CPU and if you don't want to loose any frames.

About your second question, its not clear to me what you mean. Please elaborate further.

Comment: I don't use the OpenCv to capture the images. I used Camera API to get the images from the cameras.
Still i can not see here, that the code uses stereo cameras. And i don't need to process the camera images separatly. I need two camera images at the same time, to compare them with OpenCV.
Actually the code of my programm does the same like yours. At the moment i save the images from each camera. But my question, how i can say to program "Hey the image from right and left camera is ready, compare them now". And than pause the cameras threads and go to processing the images.

Comment: I imagine you are storing the frames in memory, on some sort of array. You'll need another thread whose job will be to scan the array looking for matching timestamps. When a match is found, send them to processing/compare and pause the camera while the processing is not done (is this what you want?). When you're done with them, maybe its a good idea to pop them out of the array if you don't need them anymore and save space.